# Make an article always fill the entire page (only height-wise) (HTML+ CSS)

Tags: html, css

I would like to make an article, which will always cover the whole page. (From top to the bottom) Now I am unfortunately stuck with this [link to an image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/djL00.png). My article can get longer automatically (https://codepen.io/grojd/pen/dyOeKGq). I basically just want to have the footer always down, sticked to the bottom of the page and also want my article to connect the menu and the footer. This is my CSS of article:

```
 article {
  background: #708a91;
  opacity: 90%;
  margin: 0% 30%;
  border: 1px dotted black;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 25px 1px #cfcaca;
  height: auto; 
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please include your HTML in your question. Without it, CSS is useless to us. Please read [how to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I would like to make an article, which will always cover the whole page. (From top to the bottom)

You can use **viewport units**. There are 4 units:

- `vw` - viewport width units (each `vw` represents `1%` of the viewport width)
- `vh` - viewport height units (each `vh` represents `1%` of the viewport height)
- `vmin` - whichever is the smaller, `vw` or `vh`
- `vmax` - whichever is the larger, `vw` or `vh`

So:

```
article {
  height: 100vh;
}
```

declares that the height of `article` will always be `100%` of the viewport height.

Answer (score 0):

I got it by doing the following (remove margin, set width to 100%):

```css
article {
   background: #708a91;
   opacity: 90%;
   width:100%;
   border: 1px dotted black;
   box-shadow: 0px 0px 25px 1px #cfcaca;
   height: auto; 
}
```

That made it go edge to edge and meet the footer.

Comment: This hasn't answered my question at all.I guess it didn't becuase my question wasn't very straightforward so I made some changes to it. However, thanks.